# Pro accounts upgrades based on in-app purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile

I would like to change my iOS app from paid app to in-app purchase.

I would like to be able to do the following:

o Purchase Pro account status for X months from within the app
o Purchase Pro account status on our website 
o Upgrade users to Pro accounts status users from our system

Which of the in-app purchase types you think best - Non-renewing or 'Non-Consumable’ ?

In the guidelines it says 
"
11.1    Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected.
11.2     Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected. 
"

Is enabling purchasing the pro account status on our website or the system upgrades contradicts what mentioned in 11.1+11.2?

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

What Apple is saying in their guidelines is "You cannot get the payment for your app features, through the method other than app store purchase".

if you are going to use any payment gateway method for getting the payment and then you will unlock the premium features of your app. Apple will reject your app right away.

However, You have 3 choices:

Non-consumable: only pay once (use this if you want a free-to-pro-upgrade product)
Consumable: pay for every download
Subscription: recurring payment

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Isn't Non-Consumable are meant to be 'for life'? and if so, isn't it a bit contradicting to the fact we want users to have the Pro features for a limited time and make users repurchase it using the IAP?

Comment: You should go with subscription, Which is of two types (Auto Renewing or (Non) Auto Renewing.

But you need to maintain all the user transaction receipts on your server. Apple will not take care of it in the case of Non-Auto Renewing.